# Yii: optimize LEFT OUTER JOIN to INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, yii, relationship

I have following relation defined in *Entity* model:

```
 public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            ...
            'profile' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Profile', 'userId'),
            ...
```

Which "compiles" into *LEFT OUTER JOIN*. But I can guarantee, that each entity has related profile, so *LEFT OUTER JOIN* is excessive in this case and may eat some performance. How do I force this relation to compile into simple *JOIN* (*INNER JOIN*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the join type in relations with `joinType` like below:

```
return array(
        ...
        'profile' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Profile', 'userId','joinType'=>'INNER JOIN'),
        ...
```